# Excel average not working when averaging from an IF Statement

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a column with =IF(E2="W ",H2,IF(I2<>"",I2,"")) in it.
It displays values but when I take an average of the column, it comes up with a divide by zero error.
Is there a special type of average function I need to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that H2 and/or I2 are numbers? Perhaps those numbers are text formatted (in which case AVERAGE, not finding any true numbers will return #DIV/0! error). Try converting like this:

`=IF(E2="W ",H2+0,IF(I2<>"",I2+0,""))`

+0 will convert a text-formatted number to an actual number, then your AVERAGE function should work

Comment: May not not be a problem in this instance, but issue could arise if there are missing data values.  If both cells in columns H and I are blank, if value in column E is "W" and value in column H is blank, or if col. E value is not "W" and col. I is blank, solution would evaluate to 0 in the formula column, which would throw the average off if you didn't want to include missing values in it.

Comment: Thanks chuff. I think the latter case is covered but you are right about the former, in which case you could probably add a check for H2 being blank, i.e. =IF(E2="W ",IF(H2<>"",H2+0,""),IF(I2<>"",I2+0,""))